# SQL Decimal Issue

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, regional

I have an input string in the following format: 12.34

When I call this line:

```
db.AddInParameter(insertMessageDetailCommand, "AttachmentSize", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal  , Convert.ToDecimal(this.messageEnvelope.EnvelopeInfo.AttachmentSize));
```

I get an input string not in the correct format. The server I am deploying to have regional settings with a "," separator for decimals. But other production servers could have "." separators.

How can I pass this string value : 12.34 to this function so that it doesn't break, and its generic enough to withstand any regional setting you throw at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a culture when you parse the string to elliminate differences in server settings. You can use `InvariantCulture`, which uses period as decimal separator:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(this.messageEnvelope.EnvelopeInfo.AttachmentSize, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```